# Rest API for read one in record give null value

Tags: php

I was building a Rest API to read one record in database but the output give null value. It should give the detail of the product when the id is given. I use phpmyadmin as database for this Rest API. Below are the code and the screenshot of the output:

read_one.php

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  // include database and object files
  include_once '../config/database.php';
  include_once '../objects/product.php';

  // get database connection
  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->getConnection();

  // prepare product object
  $product = new Product($db);

  // set ID property of product to be edited
  $product->id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die();

  // read the details of product to be edited
  $product->readOne();

  // create array
  $product_arr = array(
    "id" =>  $product->id,
    "category_id" => $product->category_id,
    "title" => $product->title,
    "model" => $product->model,
    "brand" => $product->brand,
    "colour_flavour" => $product->colour_flavour,
    "price_exclude_gst" => $product->price_exclude_gst,
    "gst" => $product->gst,
    "buy" => $product->buy,
    "price" => $product->price,
    "comm" => $product->comm,
    "type_id" => $product->type_id

  );

  // make it json format
  print_r(json_encode($product_arr));
?>
```

function readOne

```
function readOne(){

    // query to read single record
    $query = "SELECT
                c.title as title, p.id, p.category_id, p.title, p.model, 
                p.colour_flavour, p.brand, p.price_exclude_gst, p.gst, 
                p.buy, p.price, p.comm, p.type_id
              FROM
                " . $this->table_name . " p
                LEFT JOIN
                    categories c
                        ON p.id = c.category_id
              WHERE
                p.id = ?
              LIMIT
                0,1";

    // prepare query statement
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );

    // bind id of product to be updated
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);

    // execute query
    $stmt->execute();

    // get retrieved row
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // set values to object properties
    $this->id = $row['id'];
    $this->category_id = $row['price'];
    $this->title = $row['title'];
    $this->model = $row['model'];
    $this->colour_flavour = $row['colour_flavour'];
    $this->brand = $row['brand'];
    $this->price_exclude_gst = $row['price_exclude_gst'];
    $this->gst = $row['gst'];
    $this->buy = $row['buy'];
    $this->price = $row['price'];
    $this->comm = $row['comm'];
    $this->type_id = $row['type_id'];
}
```

[The output of read one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc2Ts.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what went wrong with this read one function. I wrote the wrong table name which is category to categories. Sorry for the troubles.

Answer (score 0):

PhpMyadmin is not a database.

first Check yous sql query if it return any value or not.

second it seem like you use PDO to connect. try to change this line

```
// bind id of product to be updated
//$stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute(array('1'));

    // execute query
    //$stmt->execute();

    // get retrieved row
    //$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```